# Помогите перевести код с ++ на с #

Tags: c#, консоль

есть код но не получатся переписать на C#,
я пытался но пишет ошибки

```
#include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    struct Time {
      int hh, mm;
    };
    struct Train {
      string name;
      Time from, to;
    };
    istream& operator >>(istream& ist, Time& time) {
      char c;
      ist >> time.hh >> c >> time.mm;
      return ist;
    }
    int toMinutes(const Time& time) {
      return time.hh*60 + time.mm;
    }
    string getName(istream& ist) {
      char c = ist.get();
      while (c != '\"') {
        c = ist.get();
      }
      string name = "\"";
      c = ist.get();
      while (c != '\"') {
        name += c;
        c = ist.get();
      }
      name += '\"';
      return name;
    }
    istream& operator >>(istream& ist, Train& train) {
      train.name = getName(ist);
      ist >> train.from >> train.to;
      return ist;
    }
    int roadMinutes(const Train& train) {
      int minutesFrom = toMinutes(train.from);
      int minutesTo = toMinutes(train.to);
      if(minutesFrom < minutesTo)
        return minutesTo - minutesFrom;
      return 24*60 - minutesFrom + minutesTo;
    }
    int main() {
      ifstream ifst("input.txt");
      ofstream ofst("output.txt");
      const double distance = 650;
      int n;
      ifst >> n;
      Train fastestTrain;
      ifst >> fastestTrain;
      for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        Train train;
        ifst >> train;
        if(roadMinutes(train) < roadMinutes(fastestTrain)) {
          fastestTrain = train;
        }
      }
      ofst << "The fastest train is " << fastestTrain.name << ".\n"
           << "It\'s speed is "
           << round(distance / (roadMinutes(fastestTrain) / 60.0))
           << " km/h, approximately.";
    }
```

Comment: Так "помочь"  или сделать за вас?

Comment: лучше сделать, потому что я не смогу перевести ,буду благодарен

Comment: Это не тот сайт, где делают за вас. А то, что начинающий, ещё не значит, что надо быть ленивым и ничему не учиться. Иначе так толкового программиста из вас и не получится

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя просто взять и переделать это по аналогии `apple` это `яблоко`. В программировании есть определенные паттерны [Паттерны в программировании](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
и для каждого языка они могут отличатся. Поэтому подходы на решение одной и той же задачи, разные в разных языках, где-то лучше сделать так, а где-то иначе.

Поэтому отвечая на Ваш вопрос: **Вам следует сначала полностью осознать код на C++ (можете записать его [Алгоритмическим языком](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA#:%7E:text=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B8%CC%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%2C%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9,%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2.&text=%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB.)), а уже потом, при условии что Вы знаете C# переписать код под него.**

P.S Если бы было, что-то типо "онлайн конвертер языков" (которые хорошо работали), то программисты бы не изучали разные, а учили один язык

Answer (score 1):

К предыдущему ответу я бы хотел добавить, что есть еще понятие "стандартной библиотеки" для каждого языка.

Практически это означает, что набор функций, которые предназначены для решения разных элементарных задач, уже встроен в язык. И эти наборы немного разные в разных случаях.

Возьмем такой пример из кода:

```
int toMinutes(const Time& time) {
  return time.hh*60 + time.mm;
}
```

Эта функция берет структуру time и возвращает "кол-во часов и минут, преобразованное к минутам".

В C# есть тип TimeSpan, предназначенный для хранения промежутков времени, иу него есть множество "конвертеров", например:

```
    TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(1, 15, 42, 45, 750); // 1 день 15 часов 42 минуты и т.п.
    int minutes = (int)interval.TotalMinutes();
```

Поэтому то, что делает функция в C++, можно написать в одну строчку в C#.

Чтобы не быть высокомерным гадом, я хочу дать совет по методике того, как перевести программу с языка на язык.

Запустите её в среде типа Visual Studio Code. Это довольно легковесная серда, в которой можно установить множество языков, и C++ и C# там точно есть.

"Поиграйтесь" с программой - просто запустите её на разных набрах данных. Сделайте так, что Вы можете в отладчике посмотреть на работу программы.

Потом - переносите её функциональность на другой язык в другом экземпляре одновременно запущенной Visual Studio Code, вы сможете прямо в процессе переписывания программы проверять, как она работает.

Для более- менее простых алгоритмов такой способ будет работать и не будет слишком сложным.

Успехов вам!

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Согласен, не упомянул об этом. Да, способ хороший